# Why does gcc allow "int foo = foo" to compile?

Tags: c, gcc

```
int main(void) {
  int foo = foo;
  return 0;
}
```

Why is this possible to do? Wouldn't it be better if this was caught by the compiler?

Comment: Unfortunately it's valid C syntax. It makes no sense, but is still valid. And if you build with the right options [you will get warnings about it](https://godbolt.org/z/sTGfE3rEf).

Comment: FWIW, clang issues a warning (`-Wuninitialized`) for this, and GCC seems to do so as well but only in C++ mode. It is _caught_ by the compiler, but as @Someprogrammerdude points out it is valid C so the compiler is not allowed to reject it.

Comment: Related question: [Why is -Winit-self separate from -Wuninitialized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22965414/147845)

Comment: As a side note, code like `volatile uint32_t foo = foo;` might make sense apart from it being undefined behavior. You might want to clear all set flags in a hardware flag register while preserving other flags - if this is done while writing a 1 to them then that's a valid use-case scenario. Though it would be more sensible and well-defined to do `volatile uint32_t tmp = the_register; the_register = tmp;`.